# Yocto/Poky sudo not working

Tags: yocto

In my poky build, I've added a password for root, and also I've added a user "myuser". In addition I've added sudo to the list of IMAGE_INSTALL_append.

When logging as "*myuser*" and tried to "*sudo chmod*" a file using the root password, it doesn't work "*Sorry try again*"...

I can log in normally as root with my password,

Anyone has seen this, is sudo working for poky?

Comment: I haven't tested sudo in poky but it doesn't want the _root_ password in any OS... you're supposed to enter the user password (and the user needs to be in sudoers file)

Answer (score 0):

As `sudo` can be executed an you've got a `Sorry try again..` error message I think you either got your password wrong (make sure you use the users password, not roots) or you haven't configured sudo correctly.
For a description on how to use `/etc/sudoers` take a look at its manpage: https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers

Answer (score 0):

No way. There is no `su` package in Yocto/OE.

Does your image build ? You should have had something like `Missing or unbuildable dependency chain` error, unless you've created a recipe providing `su` package.

To add user with sudo capability, below is an example of what you should have in your image's recipe.

- Create the user with a suitable password
- Add the user to `sudo` group
- Give sudo capabilities to `sudo` members

I suppose you have an image recipe, or even a  bbappend on an existing one.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " sudo"

inherit extrausers
PASSWORD = "mypassword"
USER = "myuser"

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
    useradd -p `openssl passwd ${PASSWORD}` ${USER}; \
    usermod -a -G sudo ${USER}; \
"

# Here we give sudo access to sudo members
update_sudoers(){
    sed -i 's/# %sudo/%sudo/' ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/sudoers
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "update_sudoers;"
```

Comment: Yes building poky 2.1.2 core-image-base and krogoth oe; I removed "sudo" from IMAGE_INSTALL_append, and started using "su" normally.

Answer (score -3):

Problem fixed removing "*sudo*" from IMAGE_INSTALL_append, and just using "*su*" instead

Comment: You've installed `sudo` by adding `su` to `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`? Are you serious?

Comment: No, I just removed sudo IMAGE_INSTALL_append and, "su" was already part of the core-image-base

Comment: @g0hl1n what is wrong with that, i am a newbie and don't know much about.